# C++: static member variable

Tags: c++, variables, static, member, non-static

Statement: "Static member variables can be ONLY changed by static methods."

Is this statement correct, or can static member variables also be changed by non-static methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not correct. A static member can be accessed and modified by non-static member function.

Answer (score 7):

It's wrong. `static` data members can be changed by any member function. `static` methods can also be called by any member function.

It's the other way around that's impossible: `static` methods can't call non-`static` methods and can't access non-`static` members.

That's because `static` members (methods and data) are bound to a class, whereas non-statics are bound to class instances.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is incorrect. You can modify static members from any class member function and from any other function that the static member is visible from (i.e. public statics can be modified from anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

`static` data members (and static member functions) can be accessed from anywhere in the program, granted that the access specifier allows it:

```
struct test {
   void foo() {
      x = 1;
      bar();
   }
   static bar() {
      x = 2;
   }
   static int x;
};
int test::x = 0;
int main() {
   test::bar();
   test::x = 3;
}
```